# How to use Javers Query Language to fetch the values of a mapType property

Tags: javers

I have a contact entity which has a map storing phone objects.
When I add a new phone object (phone2) to the map, using JQL, I am able to detect that change though MapChange, but the acutal value of the phone object is not shown.

I can see that if I change an existing phone object (phone1), that value is being shown in the ValueChange.

Similarly, is there any way to see the value of the Phone object (phone2) that was added, directly in the MapChange?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Javers javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build();
    Map<String, PhoneInfo> phones = new HashMap<>();
    phones.put("phone1", new PhoneInfo().number("9876543210"));
    ContactInfo con = new ContactInfo().id(101L).phones(phones);
    javers.commit("author1", con);

    phones.put("phone1", new PhoneInfo().number("9876543211"));
    phones.put("phone2", new PhoneInfo().number("9876543212"));
    javers.commit("author2", con);

    QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.byInstanceId(101L, ContactInfo.class).withChildValueObjects();
    Changes changes = javers.findChanges(queryBuilder.build());

    System.out.println("changes:\n" + javers.getJsonConverter().toJson(changes));

}

public static class ContactInfo {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private Map<String, PhoneInfo> phones;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public ContactInfo id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public Map<String, PhoneInfo> getPhones() {
        return phones;
    }

    public void setPhones(Map<String, PhoneInfo> phones) {
        this.phones = phones;
    }

    public ContactInfo phones(Map<String, PhoneInfo> phones) {
        setPhones(phones);
        return this;
    }
}

public static class PhoneInfo {

    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String number;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public PhoneInfo id(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
        return this;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public PhoneInfo number(String number) {
        setNumber(number);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Output:

changes:

[

{

```
"changeType": "ValueChange",

"globalId": {

  "valueObject": "committest.domain.Contact$PhoneInfo",

  "ownerId": {

    "entity": "committest.domain.Contact$ContactInfo",

    "cdoId": 101

  },

  "fragment": "phones/phone1"

},

"commitMetadata": {

  "author": "author2",

  "properties": [],

  "commitDate": "2019-07-16T02:10:32.016",

  "commitDateInstant": "2019-07-15T20:40:32.016Z",

  "id": 2.00

},

"property": "number",

"propertyChangeType": "PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED",

"left": "9876543210",

"right": "9876543211"
```

},

{

```
"changeType": "MapChange",

"globalId": {

  "entity": "committest.domain.Contact$ContactInfo",

  "cdoId": 101

},

"commitMetadata": {

  "author": "author2",

  "properties": [],

  "commitDate": "2019-07-16T02:10:32.016",

  "commitDateInstant": "2019-07-15T20:40:32.016Z",

  "id": 2.00

},

"property": "phones",

"propertyChangeType": "PROPERTY_VALUE_CHANGED",

"entryChanges": [

  {

    "entryChangeType": "EntryAdded",

    "key": "phone2",

    "value": {

      "valueObject": "committest.domain.Contact$PhoneInfo",

      "ownerId": {

        "entity": "committest.domain.Contact$ContactInfo",

        "cdoId": 101

      },

      "fragment": "phones/phone2"

    }

  }

]
```

}

]

Comment: provide complete example with your classes definitions

Comment: @BartekWalacik, sorry, I updated the code now.